# Truecrypt volume in empty space

Tags: macos, truecrypt

A few years ago, I had a computer set up at home ,running Debian Linux.
On one of the hard drives, I had a true crypt volume. It was a full volume encryption, not a file.

The computer is since gone, and the drive has been in the cupboard for a few years, but now I want to access it.

I am connecting via USB, to a mac (and also tried a Windows PC).

On both, I can see the Linux portion on the first half of the drive (in mac this is `/dev/rdisk2s1`), but I certain the true crypt stuff is at the end of the drive. Mac and Windows just label this as empty space (so no patron created).

Is it possible that there is a true crypt volume there?
I have tried `/dev/rdisk2s1`, but told that it does not exist. I am scared to create a portion in that space, because I will probably write over a header.

Is there any way I could access this. What should I tell Truecrypt the *address* of the volume is?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [TestCrypt](http://testcrypt.sourceforge.net/) which may be able to find the volume. It only runs on Windows but should be able to find a deleted volume on an ext2/3 partition.

The [CGSecurity](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/Recover_a_TrueCrypt_Volume) website outlines an alternative:

> **Recovery using whole decryption**
>
> Another method is to permanently
> decrypt the damaged system partition/drive. You can use the [TrueCrypt
> Rescue Disk](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/rescue-disk) and next use [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk). Run TestDisk, select the drive
> letter or partition corresponding to the damaged volume, Advanced.
> TestDisk can repair the FAT/NTFS boot sector, ext2/ext3 superblock.

That site also gives alternatives for running recovery under Linux.

Comment: Thank you (sorry for very long wait)
I might need to mount the drive up in Linux and then try.
In Disk Management (Windows) the drive shows, with one partition taking half the disk, and the rest is "Unallocated". That unallocated bit is the truecrypt volume. When opening Truecrypt in windows, and trying to select a device a device, it does not show as an option.

When I used to use this volume in Linux I would mount it with truecrypt using the command line, and addressing the volume directly, something like /dev/sdb1

Comment: Have you tried the tools outlined in my answer?

Comment: This is not a system partition, so as far as I know it doesn't come with a recovery disk. I might be wrong on that.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't mention a Windows Recovery disk. Whether it is a system partition isn't relevant.